# How to use curl's response in other run commands in github actions

Tags: github-actions

Trying to get the response from curl and use it in subsequent commands. Not sure what should be the correct syntax here.

```
    - name: Get Token    
    run: |
      response = $(curl https://********* -header "Accept: application/json" -header "X-Username: ${{ secrets.USER_NAME }}" -header "X-Password: ${{ secrets.PASSWORD }}")         
      echo "response from curl= $response"
```

Comment: You could save the variable in an `output` (reference: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter). I've got this workflow example as well if you want to take a look: https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/08-outputs-workflow.yml

Comment: assigning to a variable in bash should look like `response=$(curl ...)` i.e no spaces around the `=` . Otherwise, there's no GH actions specific issue here, since it's just running shell commands.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this using below approach

```
  - name: GET all workspace
    run: | 
          curl --location --request GET 'https://api.getpostman.com/workspaces' --header 'X-API-Key: ${{ secrets.API_TOKEN }}' -o workspaces.json

  - name: read workspace id
    id: workspace 
    run: echo "::set-output name=id::$(cat workspaces.json | jq -c '.workspaces[] | select(.name == "My Workspace").id')"

  - name: print workspace id
    run: echo ${{ steps.workspace.outputs.id }}

  - name: GET api's in workspace
    run: | 
          curl --location --request GET "https://api.getpostman.com/apis?workspace=${{ steps.workspace.outputs.id }}" --header 'X-API-Key: ${{ secrets.API_TOKEN }}' -o apis.json

  - name: Read api id in workspace
    id: api 
    run: echo "::set-output name=id::$(cat apis.json | jq -c '.apis[] | select(.name == "testing-service").id')"

  - name: Print api id
    run: echo ${{ steps.api.outputs.id }}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Try to use like this

---

```
  - name: Get Token    
    run: |
      response = $(curl https://********* -header "Accept= application/json" -header "X-Username= ${{ secrets.USER_NAME }}" -header "X-Password= ${{ secrets.PASSWORD }}")         
      echo "response from curl= $response"
```

---

Answer (score 0):

For this you first need to give your step an id, then set status or output using [save-state and set-output commands](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/). The syntax for setting output or state is -

```yaml
- name: Save state
run: echo "{name}={value}" >> $GITHUB_STATE

- name: Set output
run: echo "{name}={value}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

I am catching one value from curl response and setting as output, see this -

```yaml
- name: run curl
  run: | 
    status=$(curl -s --request POST \
    --url https://x.com/api \
    --header 'Token: ${{ env.TOKEN }}' \
    --header 'content-type: application/json' \
    --data '{"parameters": {"run_workflow_test":true, "source_branch":"${{ steps.comment-branch.outputs.head_ref }}"}
    }' | jq -r '.state'); echo "status=$status" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
  id: req
```

And to access the value from another place -

```yaml
- name: test 
  run: echo "Result is ${{ steps.req.outputs.status }} "
```

Best wishes.